# how to store decoded data from json to sqlite

Tags: javascript, json, sqlite, cordova, phonegap-pushplugin

I want to decode json data coming from my website to the application.
The app is built using phonegap.
The message is coming to the app via GCM but it is showing "undefined".
I have no idea about decoding the message.

Here is the function in js :

```
                   function onNotification(e) 
                   {
                    case 'message':

                    if (e.foreground)
                    {
                        $("#app-status-ul").append('<li>--INLINE NOTIFICATION--' + '</li>');
                    }
                    else
                    {   
                        if (e.coldstart)
                            $("#app-status-ul").append('<li>--COLDSTART NOTIFICATION--' + '</li>');
                        else
                        $("#app-status-ul").append('<li>--BACKGROUND NOTIFICATION--' + '</li>');
                    }

                    $("#app-status-ul").append('<li>MESSAGE -> MSG: ' + e.payload.message + '</li>');


                    //android only
                    $("#app-status-ul").append('<li>MESSAGE -> MSGCNT: ' + e.payload.msgcnt + '</li>');
                    //amazon-fireos only
                    $("#app-status-ul").append('<li>MESSAGE -> TIMESTAMP: ' + e.payload.timeStamp + '</li>');
                break;

                case 'error':
                    $("#app-status-ul").append('<li>ERROR -> MSG:' + e.msg + '</li>');
                break;

                default:
                    $("#app-status-ul").append('<li>EVENT -> Unknown, an event was received and we do not know what it is</li>');
                break;
                   }
                  }
```

Here e.payload.message is the item to be decoded and stored into SQLite database.

When I used stringify I got the data decoded. Here is the decoded data

This is the response I got.

```
MESSAGE -> MSG DECODED: {"payload":{"0":{"medicine_name":null},"1":{"tm_1":null},"2":{"tm_2":null},"3":{"tm_3":null},"4":{"dosage":null},"5":{"medicine_name":null},"6":{"tm_1":null},"7":{"tm_2":null},"8":{"tm_3":null},"9":{"dosage":null},"10":{"medicine_name":null},"11":{"tm_1":null},"12":{"tm_2":null},"13":{"tm_3":null},"14":{"dosage":null},"15":{"medicine_name":null},"16":{"tm_1":null},"17":{"tm_2":null},"18":{"tm_3":null},"19":{"dosage":null},"20":{"medicine_name":null},"21":{"tm_1":null},"22":{"tm_2":null},"23":{"tm_3":null},"24":{"dosage":null},"25":{"medicine_name":null},"26":{"tm_1":null},"27":{"tm_2":null},"28":{"tm_3":null},"29":{"dosage":null},"30":{"medicine_name":null},"31":{"tm_1":null},"32":{"tm_2":null},"33":{"tm_3":null},"34":{"dosage":null},"35":{"diagnosis":null},"36":{"instructions":null}}
```

Now I want to know How can I store it in db using sqlite.?

Thank you.

Comment: `JSON.parse(strJson)`

Comment: Thats all?? But how can I store it in SQLite db.? actually I tried like that but it didnt work.

Comment: you have a lot of errors in the code shown. review the _switch_ syntax

Comment: This is not the complete code. I just pulled out that main thing to know how to decode it.

Comment: Show your json response

Comment: use console.log(JSON.stringify(e)); to see the received data in a readable way and paste it in your question so we can help you

Comment: To save it in a db, convert it into a string by JSON.stringify(jsonObj). And to make operations again  with a json, convert the fetched string into json object by JSON.parse(jsonStr).

Comment: Thanks a ton. JSON.stringify(e) really worked. It is showing the data now.

Comment: Add the solution that worked as answer and accept it

Answer (score 0):

Following can in all JavaScript applications, even Ionic/PhoneGap/Cordova.

Consider the following JSON:

```
[  
   {  
      "message":"How is it going",
      "fromUser":"akbaralam",
      "dateAdded":"Tue May 02 2017"
   },
   {  
      "message":"It is been so long that you saw me",
      "fromUser":"akbaralam",
      "dateAdded":"Tue May 02 2017"
   }
]
```

when this JSON is converted to string using **JSON.stringify** we get:

```
"[{"message":"How is it going","fromUser":"akbaralam","dateAdded":"Tue May 02 2017"},{"message":"It is been so long that you saw me","fromUser":"akbaralam","dateAdded":"Tue May 02 2017"}]"
```

to get the object back from string we do **JSON.parse(yourStringifiedJson)** and we will get back the JSON objects.

Hope this helped.